# SignalR in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, signalr, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to install SignalR in a blank Windows Store app via Nuget

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
```

but I got this error msg:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.0.0-rc2'. You are trying to install this package into a 
project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How to install SignalR in a Windows Store app?

Comment: I'm feeling sorry that you got an error.

Comment: Is this for a .NET app or a WinJS app?  I'd like to know how to use SignalR in a WinJS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error gives the neeeded clues to resolve this. You can't use the entire SignalR package inside of a Windows App Store app (it's the SignalR server).

Overview of packages/components:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Package-Overview

You need the client:

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the signalr client for windows store apps. you can do this by installing the following package Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -pre which will install